# Elegant way to write SpaCy NER extractor?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I've written a part of function that utilizes SpaCy's NER tagger (just the built in entities not custom), and it gets the job done but from a time perspective its extremely taxing especially since the parent program has to use this on almost 400,000 rows of data. The big block of elif statements is particularly taxing.

This is what I've written so far.

```
# From this point, this part of the function is only utilized based 
# on specific criteria matched above this line, which in this case is a string such as:


raw_string =  "I'm heading to the store at around 8:30 to pick up some tannerite and other things before I go to the range"


ana = analyzer.polarity_scores(raw_string)
                    sentiment = ana['compound']

                if (raw_string not in filt_tup) or (sentiment < -0.8):

                    doc = nlp(raw_string)
                    chunk = [(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents]

                    person_list = set()
                    org_list = set()
                    nat_rel_list = set()
                    geo_pol_list = set()
                    obj_list = set()
                    date_list = set()

                    for i in chunk:

                        if i[1] == 'PERSON' and i[0] not in junk_terms + junk_names:
                            person_list.add(('Person: ', i[0]))
                        elif i[1] == 'ORG' and i[0] not in junk_terms + junk_orgs:
                            org_list.add(('Organization: ', i[0]))
                        elif i[1] == 'NORP' and i[0] not in junk_terms:
                            nat_rel_list.add(('Nationalities or religious or political groups: \n', i[0]))
                        elif i[1] == 'GPE' and i[0] not in junk_terms:
                            geo_pol_list.add(('Countries, cities, states: \n', i[0]))
                        elif i[1] == 'PRODUCT' and i[0] not in junk_terms:
                            obj_list.add(('Specific objects: \n', i[0]))
                        elif i[1] == 'DATE' and i[0] not in junk_terms + junk_orgs:
                            date_list.add(('Specific Dates: ', i[0]))

                        matched = True

                    print(matched, '\n', raw_string, '\n', sentiment, '\n', 'Entities:', '\n',
                          person_list, org_list, obj_list, nat_rel_list, geo_pol_list, date_list)

                    master_list = [matched, sentiment, raw_string, rule,
                                   person_list, org_list, obj_list, nat_rel_list, geo_pol_list, date_list]
```

Comment: what is filt_tup here?

Comment: @ChandanGupta `filt_tup` is a tuple where the first element contains a specific part of speech tag and the second elements another tuple that contains words that belong to that tag, here is an example: `('nn', 'i'), ('md', ('will', 'can', 'could', 'shall')), ('vb', ('slap', 'punch' , 'attack')), ('prp', ('you', 'them'))]`